# If I declare a function with extern "C", should I also define it that way?

Tags: c++, header, forward-declaration, function-declaration, extern-c

In my header file, `foo.h`, I have:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int foo(int x); 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Now, in `foo.cpp`, should I also use `extern "C"`, and define:

```
#include "foo.h"

extern "C" { 
int foo(int x); 
};
```

? Or is the declaration enough to ensure C-linkage (no name mangling)?

Answer (score 3):

Marking the declaration by `extern "C"` is enough.

If the translation unit containing the declaration of your function has it with `extern "C"`, the compiler will respect this when it finally encounters the implementation - and use a non-mangled symbol inside the object file.

See this on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hnT5xjhWs).

Remember, though, that if your implementation does *not* see your header, nothing will make it extern "C" if you don't do so explicitly.

Comment: The compiler will put a C-mangled symbol inside the object file. That's typically the name from the source code with an underscore in front.

Answer (score 1):

It'd respect the first declaration

> Except for functions with C++ linkage, a function declaration without a linkage specification shall not precede the first linkage specification for that function.
>
> A function can be declared without a linkage specification after an explicit linkage specification has been seen; the linkage explicitly specified in the earlier declaration is not affected by such a function declaration.
>
> [§dcl.link](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.link#6)

```cpp
extern "C" int C1();
extern "C" int C1() { return 1; } // ok, C linkage, same as previous declaration

extern "C" int C2();
int C2() { return 1; } // ok, C linkage, preserve previous

int C3();
extern "C" int C3();   // error, only C++ linkage can specified after first declaration


int F0();
int F0() { return 1; } // ok, C++ linkage by default

extern "C++" int F1();
extern "C++" int F1() { return 1; } // ok, C++ linkage

extern "C++" int F2();
int F2() { return 1; } // ok, C++ linkage

int F3();
extern "C++" int F3(); // ok, C++ linkage can specified after first declaration
```